# svg in data uri not rendered

Tags: html, svg, data-uri, bing-maps

I try to create a svg pushpin for bing maps using dynamic generated svg ([example](http://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk#dynamicallyCreateSvgPushpin+JS)). Unfortunately it doesn't render the pin correctly on the map. I digged around and found that the bing maps API is setting the `src` to a base64 encoded image.

So I tried to copy the image source into a js fiddle and see if it's something wrong with the bing maps API or the browser.
It is working for simple images like

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50">
    <circle id="circle" cx="25" cy="25" r="25" />
</svg>
```

but a bit more complex images are not rendered

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50">
    <defs>
        <circle id="circle" cx="25" cy="25" r="25" />
    </defs>
    <clipPath id="clip"></clipPath>
    <image xlink:href="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/08b73d0a58fc120a8cc8dc561d83b3d6.jpg?s=50&d=mm" x="0" y="0" height="50" width="50" />
</svg>
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w1yn9Lo8/6/

Both images get rendered fine, if I paste them directly into HTML. What is the problem here?

Comment: The SVG Image tag isn't supported in Bing Maps as the map control takes SVGs and draws them on an HTML canvas right away. As such the image doesn't have a chance to load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use an SVG file as a data URI you can't have any external references so you'd have to encode the jpg as a data uri before encoding the wrapping SVG file as a data uri.

Comment: Is there a nice way of doing it without requesting the image via http manually?

Comment: depends whether gravatar supports CORS if it does you might be able to do it in javascript via an XMLHttpRequest.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is pushpin's SVG content cannot draw unloaded images even you use inner foreignObject in SVG.

I would use canvas instead of SVG. You can use all canvas primitives in it.

My solution is there : [Bing Maps API v8 - pushpin SVG URI image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39499841/bing-maps-api-v8-pushpin-svg-uri-image)

- preload images to object(array of object)
- draw images and/or another primitives in canvas and use canvas in pushpin